# Ruby dynamic object attributes, send vs instance variable set

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Let's say I have a simple object. I have `attr_accessor`s for the attributes I want to accept, and I want to be able to initialize with a hash of objects:

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar

  def initialize( attributes = {} )
    attributes.each do |k,v|
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

In the attributes.each block above, would it be better to use `send`, like so:

```
send "#{k}=", v
```

or to use `instance_variable_set`, like so:

```
instance_variable_set "@#{k}".to_sym, v
```

... or to do something else entirely?

The differences I can think of are:

- Using `send` would be more consistent if at some point I replaced one of the `attr_accessors` with a setter method.
- Using `send` would raise `NoMethodError` if an unexpected value was passed

I'm leaning toward `send` for these reasons -- I actually kind of like the possibility of `NoMethodError` being raised for bogus init data. However, are there any other factors I'm overlooking here, especially performance and security considerations?

I appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Comment: I'd use `send` unless I had a very good reason not to; as a general rule, I prefer my objects to use the external interface when they talk to themselves, fewer maintenance hassles that way. BTW, you can say `:"@#{k}"` if you don't want an explicit `to_sym` call.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is to use send.

Reason: Even if the accessor is not present an instance variable will be created with instance_variable_set. As you mentioned, with send you will get a NoMethodError.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try` instead of `send`. `send` will return a NoMethod error if the method is not found, `try` will return *nil* if no method is found. `try` cannot be used for instance methods.

**Example:**

```
# k is a string or symbol, v a parameter value

try(k)
#=> nil

try(k, v)
#=> nil
```

But instance variables should be set or read with methods `instance_variable_set` and `instance_variable_get`

**Example**

```
# k is a string or symbol, v a value
instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
instance_variable_get("@#{k}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The common practice is using send.

First of all, `instance_variable_set` will create a lot of extra instance variables.

Then, send uses accessor method. It is very helpful when one of the attr accessors is redefined, e.g.:

```
attr_accessor :foo

def bar=
  # something's happening here
end
```

So as to avoid `NoMethodError` you should use `respond_to?` method:

```
attributes.each do |k, v|
  send("#{k}=", v) if respond_to?(k)
end
```

It's also possible to crop extra attributes before initializing manually or using gems, e.g. `gem 'strong_parameters'`